# How to make request to sql and fetch results using lazarus

Tags: mysql, lazarus

I have problem making sql request
such as

SELECT * FROM 'users'  WHERE 1

using lazarus SqlQuery,SqlTransaction and MySql55Connection.But when I'm trying to open SqlQuery(

```
SqlQuery1.Open;
```

) it causes exception:

```
Sql statement not set.
```

Comment: https://www.google.com/#q=lazarus+sqlquery+tutorial

Comment: You have put absolutely no effort into researching this whatsoever. Stack Overflow is not a place where you come to get people to do your job for you. You need to make some actual effort. Try harder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I understood my problem. I should for first set sql request and then open query and connection. Like this:

```
SqlQuery1.Sql.text:='SELECT FROM "users" WHERE 1'
MySql55Connection1.Open;
SqlQuery1.Open;
while not SqlQuery1.EOF
begin
  //fetch result
  SqlQuery1.Next;
end;
SqlQuery1.Close;
MySql55Connection1.Close;//Close connection
```